# Adding multiple CC recipients in VBScript; Recipient.Type not working

Tags: vbscript, outlook, jsx

I am working on a jsx (extendscript project) in which I am calling a VBS snippet with app.doScript. I cannot get the email_cc and email_cc2 recipients to show up as cc; they are stuck in the main "To" sending. I will not know in advance whether they exist in the users' address book, so I am adding them as recipients than trying to set their Type.

```
var vbs = 'Dim objOutl\r';
vbs += 'Set objOutl = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")\r';
vbs += 'Set objMailItem = objOutl.CreateItem(olMailItem)\r';
vbs += 'objMailItem.Display\r';
vbs += 'strEmailAddress = "' + email_address + '"\r';
vbs += 'objMailItem.Recipients.Add strEmailAddress\r';
vbs += 'strSubject = "' + the_subject + '"\r';
vbs += 'objMailItem.Subject = strSubject\r';
vbs += 'objMailItem.Body = "' + the_bodytext + '"\r';
if (email_cc && email_cc != "") {
    vbs += 'Set cc1Recipient = objMailItem.Recipients.Add ("' + email_cc + '")\r';
    if (email_cc2 && email_cc2 != "") {
        vbs += 'Set cc2Recipient = objMailItem.Recipients.Add ("' + email_cc2 + '")\r';
        vbs += 'cc1Recipient.Type = olCC\r';
        vbs += 'cc2Recipient.Type = olCC\r';            
    }
    else {
        vbs += 'cc1Recipient.Type = olCC\r';
    }

}

if (has_attachment) {
    vbs += 'objMailItem.Attachments.Add "' + pdf_file + '"\r';
}
```

Comment: Try giving the value 2 to type instead of olCC

Comment: Thanks. I did try that. The Recipient objects alert as having type 2, but they still display in the To line.

Comment: Add `cc1Recipient.resolve` after assigning the type. Likewise for the other recipient.

Comment: Thank you. That did it. I swore I had tried resolving earlier but it had made the email disappear. Probably had tried some other variation with olCC. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following points:

1. Try to use the fully qualified name in the code with the enum name, for example:

```
OlMailRecipientType.olCC
```

2. Use the `Resolve` method which attempts to resolve a recipient object against the address book. It returns true if the recipient was resolved.
3. Call the `Save` method to apply changes made through the OOM. Sometimes it makes sense to close the item, switch to another Outlook item, and then come back to check out results. Outlook caches changes and doesn't propagate changes made using the OOM immediately.

Read more about these methods and properties in the [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/) article.

Comment: Thanks. I tried running the full Enum. When I do, I get this error message thrown from Extendscript: Error Number -2146827864. Error string: Object Required: 'OlMailRecipientType'. 

Here's the line I added: vbs+= 'cc1.Type = OlMailRecipientType.olCC\r';

If I try to resolve the Recipients, they vanish.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a VBA script to make sure everything works correctly and then translate it into a VBScript one.